# using a codebehind function with eval

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

Firstly, here is my aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSourceTeklifler">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
       <div class="panel-body">
          <strong>Teklif No.</strong>&nbsp;<%#Eval("TeklifId") %><br />
          <strong>Teklif Tarihi:</strong>&nbsp;<%#Eval("TeklifTarih") %><br />
          <strong>Teklifi Hazırlayan:</strong>&nbsp;<%#Eval("Name") %>&nbsp;<%#Eval("Surname") %><br />
          <strong>Firma Adı:</strong>&nbsp;<%#Eval("FirmaAdi") %><br />
          <strong>Ürünler:</strong><br />
          <%#Eval("TeklifSiparis") %>
          <strong>Genel Toplam:</strong>&nbsp;<%#Eval("TeklifTutar") %>$<br />
          <strong>Not:</strong><br />
          <%#Eval("TeklifNot") %><br />
          <strong>Teklif Durumu:</strong>&nbsp;<%# CheckIfApproved(Eval("Approved")) %>
           </div>
             </div>
               </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

As you can see I am trying to call a method in the last item of the repeater. Here is my code-behind method:

```
protected string CheckIfApproved(bool isApproved) 
    {
        string result;
        if (isApproved)
        {
            result = "Satışa Dönmüştür";
        }
        else
        {
            result = "Satışa Dönmemiştir";
        }
            return result;
    }
```

When I run the code I get an error like 'Compile Error' with no detailed explanation in the method calling eval line. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You're passing in a `string` as param to your method when it's expecting a `bool` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%# CheckIfApproved(Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Approved"))) %>
```

Modify code as above:

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected string CheckIfApproved(object isApproved) 
    {
        string result;
        if (bool.Parse(isApproved))
        {
            result = "Satışa Dönmüştür";
        }
        else
        {
            result = "Satışa Dönmemiştir";
        }
            return result;
    }
```

It should be fine!